# wso2 dataservice filter null for a dataservice field

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

in my Dataservice ,in a select statement one of the field has a null value.
It is returned like this

```
<ROLLNUMBER xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

I want to write a filter and do some logic based on if the value is null or it has some value.
How can do that in WSO2 ESB?
I tried a few XSL expression nothing works

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a filter mediator wherein you need to use xpath expression as `//*[local-name()='ROLL_NUMBER']/text()`, what this will do is for the element ROLL_NUMBER if there is a value only then the filter condition is satisfied and it goes to then condition if not then it will go to else condition

Comment: The actual xml comes like //m0:Entries/m0:Entry/m0:ROLL_NUMBER ..Can you give me the expression like this?

Comment: <filter xmlns:m0="http://org.example"  xpath="($body//m0:Entries/m0:Entry/m0:ROLL_NUMBER/text())"><then/><else/></filter>

Comment: After xmlns:m0="org.example" there is a semicolon ";" , you need to remove that, i don't know why that is getting added here

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<filter source="boolean(get-property('yourProperty'))" regex="false">
    <then> <!-- NULL OR NON EXIST --> </then>
    <else> <!-- EXIST --> </else>
</filter>
```